# Import data from excel to Sql database

Tags: excel

I have to import the data from excel to SQL database. Before inserting data I have to apply some business rules. So what is best approach.
1. Should I read all the excel and put it in collection and the apply business rules then
**Or**
1. I read excel, get the record , apply the business rule and insert the record in database

Answer (score 0):

I would put the data without applying any rules into the database.  Afterwards you can easily apply the business rules using SQL.

Although this approach assumes:

Your data is well-enough formatted.  Maybe one cell is not equivalent to one field?  Or maybe the Excel file was edited by several people following different editing conventions.  From my experience it's much easier to do this data cleaning *before* the import to SQL.

You are able to apply your business logic using SQL.  After all you need to be able to realize it and if you are a better VBA programmer than SQL or PL/SQL programmer, then you should probably apply the business rule *before* inserting everything into the database.

Comment: Ok and you are good in it?  How much data is it and how complex is the business rule?

Comment: This may some be some times 10,000 Records with 10 fields or columns

Comment: You should import to SQL first, then you can interactively test and look at your data using your favorite SQL client.  This will save you time when getting the implementation of the business rule right.